# query_cache_size, Qcache_total_blocks and query_alloc_block_size

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-cache

My understanding is that query_alloc_block_size determines the block size for the query cache. In my case it is the default 8K

When I calculate query_cache_size/Qcache_total_blocks I get numbers that range from 1-4K. Why would they change over time? why would they be different to query_alloc_block_size?

Also the default value for query_cache_min_res_unit is 4K. Why would that be smaller than query_alloc_block_size? Wouldn't it need to be a multiple of query_alloc_block_size?

Obviously I'm misunderstanding something quite fundamental

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't answer the specific question.

My opinion on the QC:  Turn it off if you do even a modest number of writes to the table that you are running queries against.

Some other metrics and advice (if you do turn it on):

- Size of QC -- `query_cache_size`
  Recommend 8e6 to 100e6 MB.  If out of range, Too small = not of much use.  Too large = too much overhead.  Recommend either 0 or no more than 50M.
- Pct Query Cache free -- `Qcache_free_memory / query_cache_size`
  Recommend 0 to 100%.  If out of range, lower query_cache_size 
  Lowering it releases RAM for other uses, but since the free space will vary over time, this one reading may fool you.
- Running out of room in QC -- `Qcache_lowmem_prunes / Uptime`
  Recommend 0 to 15 /sec.  If out of range, increase query_cache_size
- SQL_CACHE attempted, but ignored -- `Qcache_not_cached / Uptime`
  Recommend 0 to 40 /sec.  If out of range, Rethink caching; tune qcache
- Percent of SELECTs that were not cached in the QC. -- `Qcache_not_cached / (Qcache_hits + Com_select + Qcache_not_cached)`
  Recommend 0 to 30%.  If out of range, QC is not very useful.
- Fragmentation in Query Cache -- `Qcache_free_blocks * 4096 / query_cache_size`
  Recommend 0 to 1.  If out of range, decrease query_cache_min_res_unit
- Hit to insert ratio -- high is good -- `Qcache_hits / Qcache_inserts`
  Recommend (prefer high values) 1 - 10.  If out of range, Consider turning off the query cache.
- Hit ratio -- SELECTs that used QC -- `Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Com_select)`
  Recommend (prefer high values) 25 - 100%.  If out of range, Consider turning off the query cache.
- Query cache hit rate -- `Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Qcache_inserts + Qcache_not_cached)`
  Recommend (prefer high values) 30 - 100%.  If out of range, Probably best to turn off the QC.
- Queries cached at the moment -- `Qcache_queries_in_cache`
  Recommend (prefer high values) 500 - 100000.
- Fragmentation in Query Cache. -- `Qcache_free_blocks / Qcache_total_blocks`
  Recommend 0 to 30%.  If out of range, Various things.
- Invalidations/sec. -- `Qcache_inserts - Qcache_queries_in_cache / Uptime`
  Recommend 0 to 100 /sec.
- query_alloc_block_size vs formula -- `(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory)
  / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size`
  Recommend 0.5 to 2.  If out of range, Adjust query_alloc_block_size
- Subquery cache hit rate -- `Subquery_cache_hit / ( Subquery_cache_hit + Subquery_cache_miss )`
  Recommend (prefer high values) 60 - 100%.  If out of range, Consider SET optimizer_switch='subquery_cache=off';

Answer (score 0):

1. True
2. If query_cache_size has been SET either GLOBAL or SESSION or query_alloc_block_size has been SET either GLOBAL or SESSION, the result of query_cache_size/query_alloc_block_size = answer could be different.
   Qcache_total_blocks is always the result of this calculation, at the moment.
3. Think of query_cache_min_res_unit as minimum bytes required to store your query result.  You could store thousands of count results in one query_alloc_block_size.  Consider using the minimum of 512, to conserve QC memory.
   This link will help.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html